# Why is my drawable button layout not being applied to the button as a background?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I have created a buttonbg.xml file to give a button a round shape with a custom color.
Here's how the xml code looks like,

```
<stroke
    android:color="#69B9F9"
    android:width="3dp" />

<corners
    android:radius="200dp" />
```

But when i apply this xml as a background to the button,

```
<Button android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="227dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Nothing happens,

[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLGCS.png)

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your button

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Also in your question you've written

> I have created a buttonbg.xml file

and in your code you've written button_bg.xml. Please check if the typo exist in your code or just in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You can crate you button drawable and apply that drawable to linearlayout or any other layout. So basically create custom button it's very easy way to implement your custom button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip for when you don't want to use `app:backgroundTint="@null` each time you want to add a background to a button. Go to your **themes.xml file**. There in the first **style** tag you'll see something that says

```
<style name="Theme.[AppName]" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents...."
```

so change the **parent** to **"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"** (if you don't mind the action bar which is the thing at the top which has the name of your app) or to **"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"** (if you don't want the action bar.

So what this does is that it removes the default button styling and all giving you just a plain grey button which you might've seen in a few tutorials on youtube if you're learning from there.